# Парсинг строки в объект Java

Tags: java, android, json

Есть `String`, в которой Json ответ, как в Java можно распарсить это строку в объект?
Есть ли какие-нибудь внешние или стандартные бибилиотеки?

Comment: У вас же уже в строке JSON. Может вам надо распарсить её в объект?

Comment: Да, именно, значит неправильно задала вопрос

Comment: Есть, например, [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) и [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson).

Comment: Ну очень много подобных [вопросов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D+Json+%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3) уже задавалось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как уже было отмечено можно использовать [библиотеки](https://medium.com/@ankit.sinhal/parsing-json-with-gson-library-184d94a04dec), а можно все сделать вручную. Пример:

```
String json = "{paramsArray: [\"first\", 100],"
            + "paramsObj: {one: \"two\", three: \"four\"},"
            + "paramsStr: \"some string\"}";

JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

Object obj = parser.parse(json);
JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) obj;
System.out.println(jsonObj.get("paramsStr"));
// some string

JsonObject jo = jsonObj.get("paramsObj");
System.out.println(jo.get("three"));
// four

JsonArray ja = jsonObj.get("paramsArray");
System.out.println(ja.get(1));
// 100
```